# What does dependency/dependant mean?

Tags: oop, terminology

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/ood/understanding-dependencies.html#whatis says that (emphasis mine):

> **Whenever a class A uses another class or interface B**, then A depends on B. A cannot carry out it's work without B, and A cannot be
>   reused without also reusing B. In such a situation the class **A is
>   called the "dependant"** and **the class or interface B is called the
>   "dependency"**. A dependant depends on its dependencies.

According to Google's definition:

> a dependent or subordinate thing, especially a country or province
>   controlled by another.

Since A depends on B,  the dependency is  A and the dependant is B. This is contrary to the first quote. Or am I missing something?

Comment: I think this is just a quirk of the English language.  Dependencies are typically indicated by "include" or "using" etc, and the word "Dependant" is used much less often.

Comment: Google's definition of... dependency? Is that the *only* definition? This might be better suited to [ell.se].

Comment: Oh you already have posted it [elsewhere](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/416182). Please don't cross-post.

Answer (score 5):

Terminology is context dependent. In general, the dependency is a synonym of dependence and describes not one entity, but state.  According to [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/fr/dictionnaire/anglais/dependence):

the situation in which you need something or someone all the time, especially in order to continue existing or operating.

So it's more about a relation to something.  For example:

> *A minor child is dependent of his/her parents. The child is in a state
>   of dependency.  The dependency describes the relation between the child and its parents.*

The google definition is only one of the available definitions (see for example the [Collins dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/dependency)), the one that is especially applicable in the context of geopolitics and real estate.  For example:

> *Before 1776, America was a dependency of the British Empire.  The
>   dependency America was dependent on the Empire.*
>
> *He bought a farm with several dependencies*

The object oriented terminology is not so different from the more general definition: a dependency is a relationship between objects or classes.  Here a more formal definition from the UML 2.5 standard:

> **7.7.1:** A Dependency signifies a supplier/client **relationship** between model
>   elements where the modification of a supplier may impact the client
>   model elements.

So, restating what's in the tutorial, we can say that:

> If A has to use B, A depends on B.  There is a relation of dependency
>   from A to B.  A is said to be the dependent.

For practical reason and **language convenience**, B is often *called* the dependency (which is indeed the contrary of everyday's language). But in reality, it is still the relation of A to B that *is* the dependency.

Answer (score 0):

The thing that is dependent on something is the dependency. I am dependent on H.  I need H injected into me. H is a dependency of me.